# Как объединить файлы js или сделать так что бы при нажатии на кнопку срабатывал js код с значениями которые я взял из input

Tags: javascript, html, матрицы

html код

```
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>matrix</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index_css.css">
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function getDate()
    {
        var date = new Date();
        var hours = date.getHours();
        var minutes = date.getMinutes();
        var seconds = date.getSeconds();
        if(seconds < 10)
        {seconds = '0' + seconds;}
        document.getElementById('timedisplay').innerHTML = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;
    }
    setInterval(getDate, 0);
</script>
<div id="timedisplay"></div>
</header>
    <div class="button--">
        <a class="sliding-button">MATRIX</a>
BLUE</a><br>        
    </div>

    <div class="inpuuut">
        <input type="range" id="myrange" min="1" max="100" class="i-1">
        <!-- <input type="text" class="i-1"> -->
        <button class="b-1">OK</button>
        <div class="out-1"></div>
    </div>


<script src="js1.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

js код самой матрици название js2.js

```
const C = document.querySelector("canvas"),
  $ = C.getContext("2d"),
  W = (C.width = window.innerWidth),
  H = (C.height = window.innerHeight);

const str = "А+Б0В-Г1Д=Е2Ё Ж3З И4Й К5Л М6Н О7П Р8С Т9У Ф!Х Ц?Ч Ш.ЩЪ,Ы Ь:ЭЮ;Я",
  matrix = str.split("");

let font = 11,
  col = W / font,
  arr = [];

for (let i = 0; i < col; i++) arr[i] = 1;

function draw() {
  $.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,.05)";
  $.fillRect(0, 0, W, H);
  $.fillStyle = "#0f0";
  $.font = font + "px system-ui";
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    let txt = matrix[Math.floor(Math.random() * matrix.length)];
    $.fillText(txt, i * font, arr[i] * 0.1);
    if (arr[i] * font > H && Math.random() > 0.5) arr[i] = 0;
    arr[i]++;
  }
}

setInterval(draw, 10);

window.addEventListener("resize", () => location.reload());
```

мне надо что бы значение из input type="range" id="myrange" min="1" max="100" class="i-1"
присваевалось сюда     if (arr[i] * font > H && Math.random() > 0.5) arr[i] = 0; arr[i]++;
где значение 0.5 после Math.random() >

помогите пж

Comment: там где ссылка на матрицу находится ссайт с кодом из js2.js

Comment: Я не увидел подключение второго скрипта

Comment: если вы про js1.js он не используется в данном коде я забыл его удалить, если вы про js2.js то мне надо понять можно ли сделать кнопку которая полностью сотрёт сайт и запустит js2  в который мне надо запихнуть значение полученное из input. Или взять что бы при нажатии на  ссылку MATRIX он переходил на другой ссайт и там уже запускался скрип с значением которое получили с ползунка.

Comment: Вам бы разделить проблемы

Comment: У меня она 1 но спобота решения 2 я просто не знаю каким способом вам лучше помочь мне